# SSRS hide textbox based on number of rows in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am limiting my report to 10,000 rows in the query (TOP 10000) because if they don't specify parameters (default is all selected) it takes forever to run and to be honest isn't useful.

I created a `textbox` in the body of the report at the bottom below my `tablix`. The report has no groupings or totals or anything.  I set the Hidden property to be:

```
=IIf(CountRows("MainQuery")>=1000,False,True)
```

The text is something like "More than 9999 results were returned. Report truncated."

I get an out of scope error.  When I put `CountRows("MainQuery")` as the value of the text box, it give me the value fine.  Why doesn't it like my expression?

Comment: Bizarre. I changed the text in the box and CountRows worked. I changed it back to what I had and it worked. Expression is the same as what I had to start. Closing item.

Comment: Not sure why that works if you have multiple datasets, but glad it's working.  FYI, see my updated answer for how to specify scope for similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use Count("MainQuery") instead of CountRows.  CountRows is required to refer to the current scope.

Update: Count will work for a report with a single dataset.  For a report with multiple datasets you have to specify the scope in the expression, like so:

=iif(Count(Fields!AnyField, "MainQuery")>1000,true,false)

Comment: I get the same error "The Hidden expression for the text box ‘txtRowLimit’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset."